# What measures/precautions do I need to take before upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS (on pendrive)?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, usb-drive

As the title says, I want to know if there is anything I should delete or remove from my Ubuntu 14.04LTS before using the pendrive save of 16.04LTS to upgrade my operating system? I am a complete noob and I cannot lose any files during the upgrade as they're work files. I have installed all the current updates. I am also concerned about the black screen bug some people have reported from graphics card drivers.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Backup all your work files first.  There is a chance the upgrade may fail or you may end up with an unbootable system.  Backup all your work first so that you can do a clean install if the upgrade fails.

Do not take any chances on this if you cannot lose your work files as you say.

Comment: Thanks. So would you agree with the below poster who said a fresh install is the way forward then?

Comment: Yes.  Personally, I never upgrade any release.  A fresh installation is always better.

Answer (score 0):

ALWAYS backup before you mess around with your OS. I find that a fresh install of Ubuntu is generally the best way to go, as upgrading from an LTS version can create conflicts with other programs you may have configured previously, not to mention all the residual cached stuff that accumulates over time.

Comment: I think this is the way I am going to go. It will be a pain reinstalling everything but as you say, it will be safer. How long does the process take approx? I live in a country with a high number of blackouts and I don't want one mid-way through the process.

Comment: Probably 20 minutes, even faster depending on the write speed of your storage (on an ssd, it's usually around 10 minutes to install from scratch, no kidding). Make sure you erase your previous installation partitions using gparted on the live usb disk.

Answer (score 0):

Why take risks at all?

In case of a pendrive: get a second pendrive and install 16.04 on that one. Then copy your files over from the old pendrive to the new pendrive. If case of problems you can redo the installations as many times as you want.

And you can use the old pendrive to do the same the next time you want to start using another new operating system.

And in regards to the other answers: you should already be making backups. There is no excuse for not making backups.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get this. I meant that I have a pendrive with the download of 16.04LTS on it and I will be using that to install it. I live in a country with VERY slow and expensive internet so downloading it isn't an option, I am afraid.

I have backed up the files now but I am more concerned with bugs such as black-screen etc.